# Android achartengine empty chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using `achartengine` library, but when the chart is empty (no values) it shows nothing, I want to show the grid even though there is no line to draw, can we do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance set the visible area:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
renderer.setYAxisMin(minY);
renderer.setYAxisMax(maxY);
```

Or you could add a null value:

```
series.add(0, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE);
```